# What does "items: child" in carousel_slider (flutter package) mean?

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

In carousel_slider "items" is defined as "The widgets to be shown in the carousel of default constructor"  and "items" has a type of "{List items}". What does the "items: child" mean in the code below? To be specific which child widget does it refer to?

```
class CarouselDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      CarouselSlider(
        **items: child,**
        carouselController: buttonCarouselController,
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: false,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          viewportFraction: 0.9,
          aspectRatio: 2.0,
          initialPage: 2,
        ),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => buttonCarouselController.nextPage(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
        child: Text('→'),
      )
    ]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can ignore it (maybe a typo) and use it as the other examples:

```dart
CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
  items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber
          ),
          child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
        );
      },
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

It is just the items that you want to show on the carousel.

As the docs (https://pub.dev/documentation/carousel_slider/latest/carousel_slider/CarouselSlider-class.html) says:

> items → List<Widget>
> The widgets to be shown in the carousel of default constructor.

So you just need to provide a List of the type Widget and it can be anything: an image, container, you name it.

Answer (score 0):

It works like default constructor `ListView(children: [widgets here])` -

So just put widgets there `CarouselSlider(items: [ Text('foo'),Text('bar'),])`

For you info - CarouselSlider has named construnctor `builder()` to build widgets on demand, similiar to `ListView.builder()`